# Something's wrong with my grub.cfg

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel

I know that's pretty generic, but... I installed updates, which included a new kernel.  I removed an old kernel and got:

```
joliver@JOHN-DEV:~$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-3.13.0-46-generic gir1.2-ubuntuoneui-3.0 wireless-regdb iw
  linux-headers-3.13.0-46 crda linux-headers-3.5.0-23-generic lesstif2
  linux-headers-3.5.0-23 libubuntuoneui-3.0-1 thunderbird-globalmenu
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 197 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 340656 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
Found Windows Vista (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found CentOS release 6.6 (Final) on /dev/sdb1
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-51-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-51-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-49-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-49-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-48-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.13.0-48-generic
Found Windows Vista (loader) on /dev/sda1
Found CentOS release 6.6 (Final) on /dev/sdb1
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
error: Incorrect command.
error: syntax error.
error: line no: 146
Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
/boot/grub/grub.cfg.new file attached.
done
Purging configuration files for linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic ...
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.13.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.13.0-46-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.13.0-46-generic
```

I have no idea what the syntax error might be.  Looking at line 146 of the new cfg doesn't tell me anything useful.  I have no way of knowing what's "right" or "wrong" in all of the files in /etc/grub.d/  So how do I fix?

/etc/default/grub:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL="console"

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE="640x480"

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID="true"

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

From /etc/grub.d/00_header

```
# Gettext variables and module
if [ "x${LANG}" != "xC" ] && [ -d "${locale_dir}" ] ; then
    prepare_grub_to_access_device $(${grub_probe} --target=device ${locale_dir}) | sed -e "s/^/  /"
  cat << EOF  <-- line 146
  set locale_dir=(\$root)$(make_system_path_relative_to_its_root ${locale_dir})
  set lang=${grub_lang}
  insmod gettext
EOF
fi
```

Comment: check this file "/etc/default/grub"  for any misconfiguration

Comment: PKumar is correct.  The `/etc/default/grub` file is the one you should be looking at, as the `/boot/grub/grub.conf` file is generated from `/etc/default/grub`

Comment: /etc/default/grub is VERY basic and unchanged:

Comment: @JohnOliver what about line 146 from `/etc/grub.d/00_header `

Comment: Try replacing `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT="0"` with `#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0` in your `/etc/default/grub`